# Synchronizing an accidently deleted local SVN folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN repository on a remote server. I regularly update it with commits from my local dev machine.

I accidently deleted a sub-folder of the repository on my LOCAL machine (not on the server). Now I have tried all things to get the folder from repository on my local machine, but for some reason it does not seem to work.

As a last resort, I did a checkout of the deleted sub-folder from Repo browser. But if I now commit from a parent folder, the child-folder modified files are not included in the commit, and I need to commit them separately.

Can someone please tell me how to recover an accidently deleted folder on local machone from the SVN repo??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not able to replicate this issue using TortoiseSVN (just mentioning this because of tortoisesvn tag)

I did just solve a similar problem on command line. Regular "svn update" would not bring the folder back in, but this worked:

```
rm -rf folder
svn up folder
```

You may want to make sure you have no local changes in the folder first :-)

Comment: Hi Svemir, I was also surprised that it did not work... However, sometime later, after committing all my changes, I ensured that all other folders in were sync, went upto a parent folder, did an SVN revet, and then did an update. And it worked. So, this issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Just perform `update` action.

Comment: Hi zerkms, I performed an update action many times, but it did NOT restore the folder after which I had to checkout the folder which I mentioned created another repo under the parent one.

Comment: @r_honey: if it did not - then there is no such directory in the repo.

Comment: @r_honey: `svn dir http://repo/path/to/dir` - will you see your directory in this case?

Comment: I did not receive a notification for your comment, or maybe I missed it. I was able to see the directory on the server in SVN Repo browser. Anyways, this issue is resolved now, as per my comment to Svemir's answer below...

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Aalok Parikh: it **is** an answer. It answers the question

Answer (score 1):

Run an `svn update` (or whatever the equivalent is in Tortoise) from the folder supposed to contain your missing folder. It will restore any files not deleted through an `svn delete`.

If you `svn delete`d the folder, then you must `svn revert` it. Not sure how you would do it in Tortoise either.

Comment: Hi xr, as mentioned in reply to zerkms reply, an SVN update did NOT restore the folder on my local machine. It has NOT been deleted on the server.

Comment: If you can afford it, try renaming the parent directory (rather than deleting it, just in case) and update the "grandparent". This should restore the parent and its children, including your missing item. If this works, you can then delete the renamed parent. Some colleagues of mine used to have a similar issue and that fixed it for them.